# PhpStorm Report Builder

Tags: phpstorm, mysql-workbench, reportbuilder

Newbie - Have just developed an RDBMS using MySQL Workbench and all coded in using PhpStorm.  All working fine but now looking to develop reports.  Cannot find report builder on PhpStorm.

Any ideas or solutions to get me started to pull report info from database?

Comment: What kind of reports are you after? What is your final goal? PhpStorm is an IDE for coding. It's not an end-user tool. It has no Report Builder (as far as I understand of what you may be after). You can query your MySQL database and then export it into a few formats (CVS, XML etc) but nothing like pretty reports. If you need them, code it in PHP (or whatever other language you are using)...

Comment: How is this related to PhpStorm, or MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Thanks LazyOne, reports all coded and tested to ensure data being pulled through from database.